# Access download on git LFS file via raw.githubusercontent.com

Tags: git, github, git-lfs

I recently upgraded a video from 480p to 720p on my repo. To do this I had to use git LFS since the 720p video was more than 100 MB (which is Github's limit for file storage).

Before the upgrade, I could download the video via a link similar to this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/videos/video.mp4

Now, this link displays git LFS related information about the video (version, oid and size). I know I can use another link to download the video but I really need this link to do it (this URL as been documented somewhere I can't edit).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found a solution:

I just looked up the network traffic. The URL should be:

```
https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/<name>/<repoName>/<branchName>/raw/some/path/someFile.huge
```

Or in your case:

```
https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/user/repo/master/raw/videos/video.mp4
```