# "git show" not showing file contents for a specific commit, but instead version and size. How can I get the file contents?

Tags: git, git-lfs

I want to visualize the version of a file  at commit . For this, I type at the command line

```
git show <commit>:Repo\Path\To\File.cs
```

According to other posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338436/how-can-i-view-an-old-version-of-a-file-with-git) one, I expect to see the content of the file. Instead, the output of the command is something like

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:2b19859bbc4aba8a94563fbf8c8ee88dfda3ad348ce3f769b21651055
size 108912
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on here and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's because this is a Git LFS file, so the file itself is not in the repo.

Comment: Would I be able to get access to it without checking out the commit? @matt

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65903167/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-lfs%5D+download+file

Comment: `git cat-file --filters <commit>:some_file.txt` seems to do what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63081712/3625298